# How do i compare NDCG values?

Tags: statistical-significance, ranking

I want to compare different ranking models using the NDCG metric. I average the NDCG of the models, then use the difference between the avg. NDCGs to compare the models.

My questions:

1. What does it mean for a ranker to have 0.1 (avg.) NDCG more than another ranker? Can i say more than: "It ranks a little better"? Especially, how big a difference in NDCG would be "significant" in absolute terms?
2. Can i say something about statistical significance of the difference of the average NDCG  w.r.t the 0-Hypothesis? I'm quite unsure about whether normality assumption holds here... Especially since i'm not looking at the average of the differences, but the difference of the averages.

Answer (score 2):

After you get an insight from the 2 means, then compare the 2 NCDG arrays (do not use the means), using for example wilcoxon signed-rank test to check whether the difference previously seen is relevant or not.
In other words, you use the test paired by queries.
The same holds if you were comparing P@K, MAP etc